# How do the monsters return without the Doors of Death?

Tags: rick-riordan, the-heroes-of-olympus

During the events of *The Heroes of Olympus*, Gaea opened up the Doors of Death so that the monsters could come back easier.

However, I could find no mention of how they got back *without* the Doors. But we know that they come back, as the Furies and the Minotaur regenerate.

And if there was an easy way to get out of Tartarus, it wouldn't be such a great prison, and we see that it *is* used as a prison for the Titans.

**How do the monsters get out of Tartarus normally?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doors of death are the only *popular* pathway to Tartarus. Between both series, four entrances to Tartarus have been shown. One in the Underworld (main entrance), one in the Labyrinth (destroyed/sealed off),  one underneath Rome, and one inside Epirus, the House of Hades (via the Doors of Death, which have now been removed). As you can see there are several pits or holes which lead to Tartarus. It is through these holes that the monsters come back.

Riordan Wikia also states

> The map of Tartarus shows a door leading to the mortal world, which is presumably used by monsters after reforming.

[image: A map of Tartarus]

Sources

- Riordan Wikia
- The Books

Comment: Can you please provide a copy of the map?

Comment: http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/olympians/images/8/88/Tumblr_mud8220wku1r8wufco1_500.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150305031947